# DateTime.Now Duration +- 2 Hours?

Tags: xml, silverlight, linq, datetime

I am trying to display XML listings based on Date and Hour +- 2 hours.

I am currently using this method:

```
bool MyDateCheckingMethod(string dateString)
        {



            DateTime otherDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMddHHmmss K", null);
            // Is this today (Checking Date and Hour)
            return otherDate.Hour == DateTime.UtcNow.Hour &&
            otherDate.Date == DateTime.UtcNow.Date ;



        }
```

But I would like to change this to select listings from my XML within 2 hours of current hour.

I have tried variations of the following, but dont know enough about DateTime and was unable to find any related questions on this site and DateTime from MSDN also didn't have any related examples or information.

```
bool MyDateCheckingMethod(string dateString)
        {


            DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;

            DateTime otherDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMddHHmmss K", null);
            // Is this today (Checking Date and Hour)
            return otherDate.Hour == DateTime.UtcNow.Hour &&
            otherDate.Date == DateTime.UtcNow.Date ;
            (otherDate - now).Duration <= TimeSpan.FromHours(2);



        }
```

Comment: Yahia's answer is just fine, tho you could also simply return the result of the last line in the code you've provided.  It will give the same result.  The code could then be read: "is the difference between now and the other date-time two hours or less?" whereas Yahia's can be read "is the date-time more recent than two hours ago, and before two hours from now?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this

```
bool MyDateCheckingMethod(string dateString)
{
DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime otherDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMddHHmmss K", null);

return ( now.AddHours (-2) <= otherDate && otherDate <= now.AddHours (2) );
}
```

Comment: Genius, just what I was after, the only problem is that I need to have the Hour in Hour.UtcNow and the Date is Date.Now, because UTCnow show listings from yesterday for some reason.

Comment: not sure what you mean... perhaps you should use `DateTime.Now` instead of `DateTime.UtcNow` ?

Comment: I tried that, but if I use DateTime.Now it gives me -12 hours. Eg 5pm here listings shown from 5am

Comment: another option is to do `DateTime now = DateTime.Now.Date.Add (DateTime.UtcNow.TimeOfDay);` - this gives the current date but with the time component of UtcNow

Comment: That did the trip. Thanks so much for your help. Your a genius.  Where is the best place to learn about this sort of this, I am picking up as I go along, but a step learning curve.

Comment: try looking at MSDN... has tons of documentation... for example go to to msdn.microsoft.com and search for DateTime - there you will find all methods attributes and often some sample code

Comment: @Rhys, Yahia: I don't advise mixing like that.  You either have UTC time, and thus accept the UTC date (which has nothing to do with the local date), or you use the local time that matches the existing data.  Any other combination doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Merlyn: I agree with you... but it seems that Rhys has already data with some mixed up timezones...

Comment: @Merlyn, Yahia: Perhaps its the way my XML is created that has caused the issues, its a fairly dirty method I use to pull the info. The solution to get the time right was DateTime now = DateTime.Now.Date.Add (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay); Which is a little odd as is seems like a double positive

Comment: @Rhys: Seems like you should only need `DateTime.Now`.  It should give a identical results (ignoring errors from sampling the current time multiple times).

Comment: @Merlyn I agree, it seems that way, but for some reason only works with DateTime now = DateTime.Now.Date.Add (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay); which doesn't seem logical.